# CSS Sprites Bottom repeating

Tags: css, stylesheet, css-sprites

Can you bottom repeat a sprite background where I want the sprite to be set of the background on the bottom of the div. I have this:

```
.statistics-wrap {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: url(../img/bg-sprite.png) repeat-x 0 -306px bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px #BEE4EA solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

It doesn't seem to appear, if I remove the **bottom** it will appear but it is set in the background repeating horizontally at the top of the div which I want it to repeat at the bottom.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use pseudo elements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363535/how-to-position-an-image-sprite-at-the-bottom-of-an-element-of-unknown-height

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see something wrong with your `background` CSS property... I'll break it down

```
background:                   /* property name */
    url(../img/bg-sprite.png) /* background-image */
    repeat-x                  /* background-repeat */
    0 -306px                  /* background-position */
    bottom                    /* ummm... what?! */
```

... so the browser can't parse your CSS property. If you load this baby in Firefox and check out the Error Console ('Tools'>'Error Console') you'll see something along the lines of:

> Error in parsing value for
>   'background'. Declaration dropped.

So I know what you're thinking... just remove 'bottom', right? But what happens then...

```
background:                   /* property name */
    url(../img/bg-sprite.png) /* background-image */
    repeat-x                  /* background-repeat */
    /* background-position...               */
     0                        /* x-position */
     -306px                   /* y-position */
```

Now your background image is offset by `-306px`, which may not be at the bottom of the `<div>`. If you're really unlucky it'll even be way past the bottom of the `<div>` and noone can see your background image.

So try something more like this...

```
background: url(../img/bg-sprite.png) repeat-x 0px bottom
```

or...

```
background: url(../img/bg-sprite.png) repeat-x -306px bottom
```

... depending on why you had that `-306px` there in the first place.

Comment: "... depending on why you had that -306px there in the first place" I must agree with Richard, the sprite term ofcourse implies that you have multiple imagery in one file. What you wish to accomplish i'm pretty sure is not going to go well with a sprite, save the pain for a rainy day, and put your background in a seperate single file. Sprites is good for wrappers (div) with fixed width and height, ie. icons, sliding doors and so on!

Answer (score 1):

background: url(../img/bg-sprite.png) repeat-x -306px 100%;

But i'm not sure that a sprite will be a good idea, for what i think you wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `bottom:0;` on it's own line and removing it from `background:`?