# How to position an image sprite at the bottom of an element of unknown height

Tags: css, css-sprites, background-image

I am using an image sprite that consisting of four "sub-images": four corners for a `div` element. The sprite is 40px by 40px. Each "sub-image" is 20px by 20px. Each corner's "sub-image is on the opposite corner of the sprite of where it would be on the dev element. For example, the top-left sub-image is at the bottom-right of the sprite.

This `div` element is 440px wide and 100% tall. I've got the top corners down but how do I get the bottom corners? Is there a way to do this without creating a new sprite? Here is what I've got so far for my CSS rule.

```
background: -20px -20px no-repeat url(<path>), 420px -20px no-repeat url(<path>);
```

Comment: I don't know if this is possible with straight CSS.  You might need to crack open some JavaScript and get the height of the element and adjust the CSS for the sprites with that value.

Comment: If I were to do that, I suppose I would have to handle resizing the browser too. Which, I would rather do two sprites instead of using JS. :(

Comment: That would certainly be a better way than JavaScript in this case.  And then you wouldn't have to confuse yourself with opposite corner images, you can have a 'top' sprite, and a 'bottom' sprite (still opposite edges though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `background-images` on `absolute`ly positioned pseudo-elements.

<del>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54gH4/)</del>

Sorry, misread your question, here is the same technique with a 'sprite':

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54gH4/1/)